# Permanently change database of an OLE DB Connection

Tags: c#, database, ole

I'm working with an OLE DB Connection that has to change databases at runtime. I have found the ChangeDatabse method to be somewhat useful, but as soon as I close the connection it resets back to the original value of the connection string.

Since my connection string could be written for a number of servers I would like to avoid changing it directly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use `DbConnectionStringBuilder`

```
System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder builder = 
    new System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder();
builder["Data Source"] = "(local)";
builder["integrated Security"] = true;
builder["Initial Catalog"] = "AdventureWorks;NewValue=Bad";
```

So you could change the Initial Catalog like `builder["Initial Catalog"] = "whatever";`

It contains `ConnectionString` property as well to get the connection string.

Have a look as [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. Will this be db-type independent?

Comment: It will just help you to build your connection string efficient. And as per my knowledge its db-type independent. The DbConnectionStringBuilder performs no checks for valid connection string. Therefore, it is possible using this class to create invalid connection strings.

Comment: Mark it as answer if you find it useful.